# Client Side redirect to new page in Sharepoint (2010) usercontrol

Tags: sharepoint

I want to redirect to new page on a button click in sharepoint usercontrol i have tried the following but its not redirecting .In my UC i have the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function Redirect() {

        var text = $('#txtTitle').val();
        window.location.href = "../Pages/Search.aspx?t=" + text;
    }

 </script>

 <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" runat="server" OnClientClick="Redirect()" />
```

Comment: when i used  <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick ="Redirect()" /> instead of asp:button its redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not redirected to your search page because the Asp Button does a postback.

Update the Button to:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" runat="server" OnClientClick="Redirect(); return false;" />
```

You also need to update your javascript code according to Focas answer.

Regards,
Martin

Comment: Thanks martin thats the catch **return false;**

Answer (score 0):

When you change html to webcontrol you need to use the clientID of your textbox, as it is changed by the server. Try to use this instead:

```
var text = $("<%= txtTitle.ClientID %>").val();
```

additionally you can even use jquery only:

```
var text = $('input[id$="txtTitle"]').val();
```

Comment: Thanks Foca i tried even that its not about the value its about redirectign any how tanks for your help